# what's the best way to fast copy some big file from serval servers to hunderands servers?

Tags: linux, bash, copy, sh

there is a big file on serval of my servers,  which i want to copy  to all my servers as fast as possible. 
below is  current script, is there a faster way to do this, like viral distribution, 
for example:  source is A, targets are B C D.
A->B, after B is done ,then B->C , A->D (at the same time) . 
how can i improve the script, any sugesstion, thanks !

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u

SOURCE_POOL=(seq -f 10.10.10.%g 10 20)

HOST_IP_LIST=(seq -f 10.10.10.%g 21 200)




READY_FLAG=/tmp/READY_FLAG
LOCK_FLAG=/tmp/LOCK_FLAG


do_lock(){
    ip=$1;shift 1
    ssh root@$ip "touch $LOCK_FLAG"
}

do_unlock(){
    ip=$1;shift 1
    ssh root@$ip "rm -f $LOCK_FLAG"
}

find_source(){
    while true;do
        for source_ip in ${SOURCE_POOL[@]}
        do
            ping $source_ip -c 1 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
            if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then
                continue
            fi  

            ssh root@$source_ip "ls $LOCK_FLAG" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
                continue
            fi

            ssh root@$source_ip "ls $READY_FLAG" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
            if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then
                continue
            fi  

            do_lock $source_ip
            echo $source_ip
            return 0
        done

        for source_ip in ${HOST_IP_LIST[@]}
        do
            ping $source_ip -c 1 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
            if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then
                continue
            fi  

            ssh root@$source_ip "ls $LOCK_FLAG" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
                continue
            fi

            ssh root@$source_ip "ls $READY_FLAG" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
            if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then
                continue
            fi  

            do_lock $source_ip
            echo $source_ip
            return 0
        done
        sleep 3
    done
    return 1
}

do_scp(){
    source_ip=$1;shift 1
    target_ip=$1;shift 1
    ssh root@$target_ip "scp root@$source_ip:~/some_big_file.tar ."

    ssh root@$target_ip "touch $READY_FLAG"
    do_unlock $source_ip
}


scp_all(){
    for target_ip in ${HOST_IP_LIST[@]}
    do
        source_ip=$(find_source)
        do_scp $source_ip $target_ip &
    done
}


do_wait(){
        local flag=1
        while [[ $flag -eq 1 ]];do
                flag=0
                for ip in ${HOST_IP_LIST[@]}
                do
                        scp_num=`ssh root@$ip  "ps -ef | grep scp | grep -v grep | wc -l" `
                        if [[ $scp_num -ne 0 ]];then
                                flag=1
                                break
                        fi
                done
                sleep 30
        done
}
scp_all
do_wait
```

Comment: I'd research torrent solution, maybe look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65387/is-there-bittorrent-software-that-runs-in-a-terminal).

Comment: Hmm, 'fast' is kinda relative (how big is the data pipe? network quality the same to all destinations? etc...)  If faster == 'more at once' then a parallel copy process (or perhaps rsync run in parallel) might improve things; if faster == 'all at once' then perhaps a single read-only mount point shared by all nodes; if faster == replicate to all systems as quickly as possible then you have to think differently, i.e. a 'mesh-style' approach to file replication (each node passes on to additional nodes - a bit more complicated, but, most likely, much 'faster'... 'torrent' sounds reasonable.)  :)

Comment: thanks for reply! for some reason, it's not allowed to install additional softwares on these servers, so no bt, no rsync, only shell or python script using scp. network speed is about 200 MB/s, file size is more than 300G.  'fast' means 'more at once', is it possible to do 'torrent ' , using python or bash? thank!